# Stop fadeTo() in jquery

Tags: jquery

I used

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#main ul li").hover(function(){

var fade = $('img.g-img', this);
fade.fadeTo('slow', 0.5);


$("#main ul li").removeClass("active");
$(this).toggleClass("active");

});


});
```

I want to stop fade, when mouseout.
This code not working:

```
fade.stop().fadeTo('slow',1)
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass two parameters to `hover`.  (A `mouseenter` handler and a `mouseleave` handler)

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main ul li").hover(
        function() { //mouseenter handler
            var fade = $('img.g-img', this);
            fade.fadeTo('slow', 0.5);

            $("#main ul li").removeClass("active");
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
        }, 
        function () {  //mouseleave handler
            var fade = $('img.g-img', this);
            fade.stop().fadeTo('slow',1)
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: in your mouseleave handler, fade is out of scope.  You'll need to define fade before calling hover(), or define it in your mouseleave handler too.

Answer (score 2):

The `fade` variable you are defining is only in scope within the event handler. Plus you need two event handlers for `hover()`: one for when the mouse enters and another for when it leaves.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#main ul li").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active").find("img.g-img").stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeclass("active").find("img.g-img").stop().fadeTo("slow", 1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi cletus;
Thanks for help.
This code not remove the previous fading